# Unable to insert into MySQL database upon checkout and payment

Tags: php

I have been working on a `LAMP` Server project which is a hotel booking website. The flow is that once the user selects the hotel, the user will check to confirm the number of adults and children for a particular room, and then proceed to payment which will then insert the user's payment credentials into the `MySQL` database. However, the issue is that it is not inserting the user's payment credentials into the database.

**checkout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Include necessary files and functions
include '../inc/hotel.database.inc.php';

// Initialize variables
$error_message = '';

// Check if hotel ID and package ID are provided in the URL and are numeric
if (isset($_GET['hotel_id'], $_GET['package_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['hotel_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['package_id'])) {
    // Retrieve hotel details and package details
    $hotel_id = intval($_GET['hotel_id']);
    $package_id = intval($_GET['package_id']);
    $selected_hotel = get_hotel_by_id($hotel_id);
    $selected_package = get_package_by_id($package_id);
    $selected_packagePrice = intval($_GET['hotel_price']);

    // Check if the hotel and package are valid
    if ($selected_hotel && $selected_package) {
        // Check if the form is submitted
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            // Validate number of adults and children
            $adults = intval($_POST['adults']);
            $children = intval($_POST['children']);

            // Perform validation to ensure sufficient rooms are available
            $available_rooms = $selected_package['quantity'];
            if (($adults + $children) <= $available_rooms) {
                // Calculate total amount
                $total_amount = $selected_package['price'] * ($adults + $children);

                // Redirect to payment page with necessary details
                header("Location: ../payment/payment.php?hotel_id=$hotel_id&package_id=$package_id&adults=$adults&children=$children&total_amount=$total_amount");
                exit();
            } else {
                // Insufficient rooms available, set error message
                $error_message = "Insufficient rooms available for booking.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Invalid hotel ID or package ID, set error message
        $error_message = "Invalid hotel or package.";
    }
} else {
    // Hotel ID or package ID not provided or not numeric, set error message
    $error_message = "Invalid hotel or package ID.";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Checkout</title>
    <?php include "../inc/head.inc.php"; ?>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include "../inc/topbar.inc.php"; ?>
    <?php include "../inc/nav.inc.php"; ?>

    <main class="checkout-container">
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <?php if (!empty($error_message)) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <?php echo $error_message; ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <h2>Confirm Booking Details</h2>
            <div class="hotel-details">
                <!-- Display hotel information here -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="../img/<?php echo $selected_hotel["hotel_url"]; ?>" alt="Hotel Image" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <h3><?php echo $selected_hotel["hotel_name"]; ?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $selected_hotel["hotel_location"]; ?></p>
                        <!-- Display room type and package details -->
                        <p>Room Type: <?php echo $selected_package['room_type']; ?></p>
                        <p>Description: <?php echo $selected_package['description']; ?></p>
                        <p>Price: $<?php echo $selected_hotel['hotel_price']; ?></p>
                        <!-- Display other relevant hotel information -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form action="process_checkout.php" method="post"> <!-- Assuming process_checkout.php is the script handling the form submission -->
                <!-- Include a hidden input field to pass hotel_id -->
                <input type="hidden" name="hotel_id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['hotel_id']); ?>">

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="adults" class="form-label">Adults</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="adults" name="adults" min="1" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="children" class="form-label">Children</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="children" name="children" min="0" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Proceed to Payment</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>


    <?php include "../inc/footer.inc.php"; ?>
    <?php include "../inc/jslibraries.inc.php"; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

**process_checkout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include "../inc/hotel.database.inc.php";

// Check if form data is complete
if (isset($_POST['hotel_id'], $_POST['adults'], $_POST['children'])) {
    // Retrieve form data
    $hotel_id = intval($_POST['hotel_id']);
    $adults = intval($_POST['adults']);
    $children = intval($_POST['children']);

    // Validate the form data
    if ($hotel_id > 0 && $adults >= 0 && $children >= 0) {
        // Redirect to payment.php with hotel ID, adults, and children
        header("Location: ../payment/payment.php?hotel_id=$hotel_id&adults=$adults&children=$children");
        exit(); // Stop further execution
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Process Checkout</title>
    <?php include "../inc/head.inc.php"; ?>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include "../inc/nav.inc.php";

    if (isset($hotel_id, $adults, $children)) {
        if ($hotel_id <= 0 || $adults < 0 || $children < 0) {
            // Display error message if form data is invalid
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Invalid form data.</div>";
        }
    } else {
        // Display error message if form data is incomplete
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Form data is incomplete.</div>";
    }

    include "../inc/footer.inc.php";
    include "../inc/jslibraries.inc.php";
    ?>
</body>
```

**payment.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include '../inc/hotel.database.inc.php';

$selected_hotel = null;
$total_price = 0;

// Function to calculate the total price based on hotel details, number of adults, and number of children
function calculate_total_price($hotel, $adults, $children)
{
    // Sample calculation: Assuming price per room and additional charges for adults and children
    $price_per_room = $hotel['hotel_price']; // Adjust this based on your database structure
    $additional_adult_charge = 20; // Adjust as needed
    $additional_child_charge = 10; // Adjust as needed

    // Calculate total price
    $total_price = ($price_per_room * $adults) + ($price_per_room * $children) + ($additional_adult_charge * $adults) + ($additional_child_charge * $children);

    return $total_price;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['selected_hotel_id'])) {
    $selected_hotel = get_hotel_by_id($_SESSION['selected_hotel_id']);  // Retrieve the selected hotel ID from the session
    // Assuming the price is retrieved from the database or calculated based on the selected hotel and room type
    // You may need to adjust this calculation based on your actual implementation
    $total_price = calculate_total_price($selected_hotel, $_GET['adults'], $_GET['children']);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Payment</title>
    <?php include "../inc/head.inc.php"; ?>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include "../inc/topbar.inc.php"; ?>
    <?php include "../inc/nav.inc.php"; ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mt-5">Payment Details</h1>
        <main class="payment-container">
            <!-- Display selected hotel's details -->
            <div class="mb-4">
                <h3>Selected Hotel</h3>
                <?php if ($selected_hotel) : ?>
                    <p>Name: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($selected_hotel['hotel_name']); ?></p>
                    <p>Location: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($selected_hotel['hotel_location']); ?></p>
                    <!-- Add more details as needed -->
                <?php else : ?>
                    <p>No hotel selected.</p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Display total price -->
            <div class="mb-4">
                <h3>Total Price</h3>
                <p>$<?php echo $total_price; ?></p>
            </div>

            <!-- Payment form -->
            <form action="process_payment.php" method="post" class="mt-4">
                <!-- Hidden input field to store hotel_id -->
                <input type="hidden" name="hotel_id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($hotel_id); ?>">
                <!-- Automatically populated user_id field -->
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_id'] ?? ''); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="selected_payment_method" name="selected_payment_method">

                <!-- Additional payment details fields (credit card, PayPal, etc.) -->
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="payment_method" class="form-label">Payment Method:</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="payment_method" name="payment_method" required>
                        <option value="">Select Payment Method</option>
                        <option value="credit_card">Credit Card</option>
                        <option value="paypal">PayPal</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <!-- Credit card fields -->
                <div id="credit_card_fields" class="mb-3" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="card_number" class="form-label">Credit Card Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="card_number" name="card_number" maxlength="16">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="expiry_date" class="form-label">Expiry Date (MM/YYYY):</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="expiry_date" name="expiry_date" pattern="\d{2}/\d{4}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="cvv" class="form-label">CVV:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cvv" name="cvv" maxlength="3">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- PayPal email field -->
                <div id="paypal_email_container" class="mb-3" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="paypal_email" class="form-label">PayPal Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="paypal_email" name="paypal_email">
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pay Now</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </main>
    </div>
    <?php include "../inc/footer.inc.php"; ?>
    <?php include "../inc/jslibraries.inc.php"; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

**process_payment.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include '../inc/hotel.database.inc.php';

// Function to validate credit card numbers (Mastercard/VISA) - basic check
function validateCreditCard($card_number)
{
    $visa_pattern = "/^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/";
    $mastercard_pattern = "/^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/";

    return preg_match($visa_pattern, $card_number) || preg_match($mastercard_pattern, $card_number);
}

// Improved function to validate expiry date (placeholder, implement Luhn algorithm for full validation)
function validateExpiryDate($expiry_date)
{
    // Basic check for format (MM/YYYY)
    if (preg_match("/^\d{2}\/\d{4}$/", $expiry_date)) {
        $expiry_parts = explode("/", $expiry_date);
        $month = (int) $expiry_parts[0];
        $year = (int) $expiry_parts[1];
        // Simple check for future date (assuming current month and year)
        return $year > date('Y') || ($year == date('Y') && $month >= date('m'));
    }
    return false;
}

// Improved function to validate CVV (placeholder, implement length and format checks)
function validateCVV($cvv)
{
    return strlen($cvv) === 3; // Basic check for length
}

// Check if form data is complete
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['user_id'], $_POST['payment_method'], $_POST['hotel_id'], $_POST['total_price'])) {
        // Retrieve form data
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $payment_method = $_POST['payment_method'];
        $hotel_id = $_POST['hotel_id'];
        $total_price = $_POST['total_price'];

        // Validate user_id, hotel_id, and total_price (you may perform additional validation here)

        // Validate payment method and process accordingly
        if ($payment_method === 'credit_card') {
            // If payment method is credit card, validate credit card details
            if (isset($_POST['card_number'], $_POST['expiry_date'], $_POST['cvv'])) {

                $card_number = $_POST['card_number'];
                if (!validateCreditCard($card_number)) {
                    header("Location: payment.php?error=invalid_card_number");
                    exit();
                }

                $expiry_date = $_POST['expiry_date'];
                if (!validateExpiryDate($expiry_date)) {
                    header("Location: payment.php?error=invalid_expiry_date");
                    exit();
                }

                $cvv = $_POST['cvv'];
                if (!validateCVV($cvv)) {
                    header("Location: payment.php?error=invalid_cvv");
                    exit();
                }

                // **Hash or encrypt card number before storing** (security improvement)
                $hashed_card_number = hash('sha256', $card_number);

                $query = "INSERT INTO travela_payment (user_id, card_number, expiry_date, cvv, payment_method) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bind_param("issss", $user_id, $hashed_card_number, $expiry_date, $cvv, $payment_method);

                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    header("Location: thankyou.php");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    header("Location: payment.php?error=payment_failed");
                    exit();
                }

                // Close the prepared statement and database connection
                $stmt->close();
                $connection->close();
            }
        } else if ($payment_method === 'paypal') {
            // Implement PayPal API integration using libraries like PayPal SDK for PHP
            // You'll need to obtain your PayPal credentials and configure the integration

            if (isset($_POST['paypal_email'])) {
                $paypal_email = $_POST['paypal_email'];

                $query = "INSERT INTO travela_payment (user_id, paypal_email, payment_method) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bind_param("iss", $user_id, $paypal_email, $payment_method);

                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    header("Location: thankyou.php");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    header("Location: payment.php?error=payment_failed");
                    exit();
                }

                // Close the prepared statement and database connection
                $stmt->close();
                $connection->close();
            } else {
                header("Location: payment.php?error=missing_paypal_email");
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: payment.php?error=invalid_payment_method");
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: payment.php?error=incomplete_form_data");
        exit();
    }
} else {
    // Request method is not POST
    header("Location: payment.php?error=invalid_request_method");
    exit();
}

        
        </html>
```

**Table to insert user's payment credentials**

```
Table: travela_payment
Columns:
payment_id int AI PK 
user_id int UN 
card_number varchar(16) 
expiry_date date 
cvv varchar(3) 
payment_method enum('credit_card','paypal') 
paypal_email varchar(255)
```

**hotel.database.inc.php**

```
<?php

// Function to connect to database
function connect_to_database() {
    $config = parse_ini_file('/var/www/private/db-config.ini');
    if (!$config) {
        die("Failed to read database config file.");
    }
    $conn = new mysqli($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    return $conn;
}

// Function to get all hotels from the database
function get_all_hotels() {
    $conn = connect_to_database(); // Call connect to database
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM travela_hotels");
    if (!$stmt) {
        die("Error in SQL query: " . $conn->error);
    }
    
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $all_hotels = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $all_hotels[] = $row;
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    
    return $all_hotels;
}

function get_hotel_by_id($hotel_id) {
    // Establish a database connection
    $conn = connect_to_database();
    
    // Prepare and execute the query to retrieve hotel details
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM travela_hotels WHERE hotel_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $hotel_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // Fetch hotel details
    $hotel = null;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $hotel = $result->fetch_assoc();
        
        // Prepare and execute the query to retrieve packages associated with the hotel
        $packages_stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tp.package_id, p.room_type, p.quantity, p.description, p.packages_url
                                         FROM travela_hotel_packages tp 
                                         JOIN travela_packages p ON tp.package_id = p.package_id 
                                         WHERE tp.hotel_id = ?");
        $packages_stmt->bind_param("i", $hotel_id);
        $packages_stmt->execute();
        $packages_result = $packages_stmt->get_result();

        // Fetch packages associated with the hotel
        $packages = array();
        while ($row = $packages_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $packages[] = $row;
        }

        // Assign packages to the hotel
        $hotel['packages'] = $packages;
    }

    // Close statements and connection
    $stmt->close();
    $packages_stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

    return $hotel;
}

function get_package_by_id($package_id) {
    $conn = connect_to_database();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM travela_packages WHERE package_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $package_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $package = null;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $package = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    return $package;
}


function get_top_3_hotels() {
    $conn = connect_to_database();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM travela_hotels ORDER BY hotel_price ASC LIMIT 4");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $top_3_hotels = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $top_3_hotels[] = $row;
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    return $top_3_hotels;
}

function search_hotels($destination){
    $conn = connect_to_database();
    // Convert both the search term and the data in the database to lowercase
    $destination = strtolower($destination);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM travela_hotels WHERE LOWER(hotel_name) LIKE '%$destination%' OR LOWER(hotel_country) LIKE '%$destination%'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $search_results = [];
    // Collect the search results into an array
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Sanitize output to prevent XSS attacks
        $hotel_name = htmlspecialchars($row['hotel_name']);
        $hotel_location = htmlspecialchars($row['hotel_location']);
        // Add hotel information to the search results array
        $search_results[] = $row;
        // $search_results[] = [
        //     'hotel_name' => $hotel_name,
        //     'hotel_location' => $hotel_location,
        //     // Add more information as needed
        // ];
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    return $search_results;
}


?>
```

**Errors I'm getting in checkout and payment pages**

```
No hotel selected
Undefined array key "hotel_price" in /var/www/html/checkout/checkout.php on line 20
```

Comment: Have you done some basic debugging - especially as it gives you *Undefined array key "hotel_price"* which is a good starting point to see what data you are being sent from the form.

Comment: time to learn how to debug your code. I wrote an introductory chapter on [debugging](https://www.phpdelusions.net/basic_principles_of_web_programming#debugging) which should help you to get going